# $natural order avoids indexes. How does orderby effect the use of indexes?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing, query-performance

Profiling slow queries I found something really strange: For the following operation the entire collection was scanned (33061 documents) even though there is an index on the query parameter family_id:

```
{
    "ts" : ISODate("2013-11-27T10:20:26.103Z"),
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "mydb.zones",
    "query" : {
        "$query" : {
            "family_id" : ObjectId("52812295ea84d249934f3d12")
        },
        "$orderby" : {
            "$natural" : 1
        }
    },
    "ntoreturn" : 20,
    "ntoskip" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 33061,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 91,
    "lockStats" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(83271),
            "w" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(388988),
            "w" : NumberLong(22362)
        }
    },
    "nreturned" : 7,
    "responseLength" : 2863,
    "millis" : 393,
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "user" : "mydb"
}
```

After some Google searches without results I found out that leaving out the `"$orderby": { "$natural" : 1}` the query is very fast and only 7 documents are scanned instead of 33061. So I assume using `$orderby` in my case does avoid using the index on family_id. The strange thing is that the resulting order is not different in either case. As far as I understand $natural order it is tautologically to use  `"$orderby": { "$natural" : 1}` or no explicit order. Another very interesting observation is that this issue does not arise on capped collection!!

This issue  arises the following questions:

1. If not using any ordering/sorting, shouldn't the resulting order be the order on disk, i.e. `$natural` order?
2. Can I create a (compound-)index that would be used sorting naturally?
3. How can I invert the ordering of a simple query that uses an index an no sorting without severe performance losses?
4. What happens behind the scenes when using query parameters and orderby? Why is this not happening on capped collections? I would like to understand this strange behaviour.
5. Are the answers of the above questions independent of whether you use sharding/replication or not? What is the natural order of a query over multiple shards?

Note I am using MongoDB 2.2. There is a ticket related to this issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5672. Though it seems in that ticket that the issue occures in capped collections too, which I cannot confirm (maybe due to different mongo versions).

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I understand $natural order it is tautologically to use
>   "$orderby": { "$natural" : 1} or no explicit order.

This is a misdescription of $natural order.  MongoDB stores records in a some order on disk and keeps track of them via a doubly linked list.  $natural order is the order that you get when you traverse the linked list.  However, if you do *not* specify $natural, that *is* what you will always get - not random order, not insertion order, not physical disk order, but "logical" disk order - the order they appear in when traversing the linked list.

> If not using any ordering/sorting, shouldn't the resulting order be
>   the order on disk, i.e. $natural order?

Yes, assuming that you understand that "disk order" is not strictly physical order, it's order they are in the linked list of records.

> Can I create a (compound-)index that would be used sorting naturally?

I don't know what you mean by sorting naturally - if you are using an index during a query, the documents are traversed in index order, not in $natural order.

> How can I invert the ordering of a simple query that uses an index and no sorting without severe performance losses?

You cannot - if you are using an index then you will get the records in index order - your options are to get them in that order, in reverse of that order or to create a compound index where you index by fields you are searching *and* field(s) you want to sort on.

> What happens behind the scenes when using query parameters and orderby? Why is this not happening on capped collections? I would like to understand this strange behaviour.

What happens depends on what indexes are available, but the query optimizer tries to use an index that helps with both filtering and sorting - if that's not possible it will pick the index that has the best actual performance.

> Are the answers of the above questions independent of whether you use
>   sharding/replication or not? What is the natural order of a query over
>   multiple shards?

It's some non-deterministic merge of $natural orders from each individual shard.

Comment: Hmm maybe the documentation should say more about what you just mentioned above, and also I remember being told by eliot that mongodb returns in find order `:/` when I asked if you can rely on the order always being static

Comment: you can only rely on it being static if your database is static - aka completely unchanging - and that wouldn't be much of a database, would it?  you should *not* rely on find order (aka $natural order) to be predictable because as you do more write operations, the $natural order can and will change.